# woocommerce hide add to cart based on custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to hide the Add to Cart button on Woocommerce product page (single page). I tried everything, but i still havent figure it yet.

So, I have a custom field named `Available` in which I enter "1" or "0".  Now, for the product for which I set this custom field to 0 - I want the ADD TO CART button to be disabled.

In product listing page I used:
`get_post_meta($post->ID, 'available', true);` and it is working, but in single page (product page)  the `get_post_meta` is not working.

I'm thinking that I should get this done by using a function?  Or some code inside the `variation-add-to-cart.php`.

Could you please help?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Write this code your-theme/functions.php

```
 if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'available', true)) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
```

Comment: please comment if working or not means in both case?

Comment: Ok please you write this code top of your functions.php  echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'available', true); exit; then check it which value they return?

Comment: my page goes blank after inserting   echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'available', true); exit;

Comment: do you think it is an error due to wc-add-to-cart-variation script?  i am still trying to figure it out

Comment: anything? what do you think?

Comment: Ok please wait i will do then i wll send to you

Comment: Anything? Still trying to figure this out... :((